# How to write inline formula involving tilde sign

Tags: math-mode, tilde

How to write following inline formula in LaTeX: `r~[0,1]`

Comment: This post doesn't show much research effort. Please consider reading [Lecture notes for teaching LaTeX to a beginner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198235/5764) and [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764) (here is the [Detexify output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XFw1i.png)).

Comment: Itried this; but not desired output and error comes;$r\backsim U{[0,1]}$

Comment: This worked,thanks; $r \sim U[0,1]$

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
...
$r\sim[0,1]$ or $r\thicksim[0,1]$
```